# Putting Multiple PCBs in a Single Panel

Tags: pcb, altium

I have 5 different designs in ***Altium Designer***, each with a *PCB*. I would like to put all PCBs together in a single panel, how could I do that?There are examples for Kicad, however I use Altium Designer.

Comment: The example is for Kicad software, I use Altium Designer

Comment: look up "embedded board array" in the manual,it's very simple

Comment: Before you do it, make sure the PCB manufacturer is OK with multiple designs in one panel.   Low cost manufacturers may not allow it at all.

Comment: Even if they allow it, I have heard stories from manufacturers where they prefer to panalize themselves. They are more familiar with their process and dimensions so know better what works well or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new PCB file to represent your panel.

Go to "place->embedded board array/panelise" in the PCB editor.

It should be pretty obvious from there, if you really want the fully documentation you can find it at http://wiki.altium.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4426668

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new PCBDoc file in your project
2. Add as many board arrays as designs you want in your panel

[image]

3. Link each array to a design and select the quantity, distance between each board,...

[image]

4. Profit!

If you're going to send this to be mounted, be sure to ask about panel dimensions in order to make life easy for them

Comment: Hello, Why are the boards in the panel green? How to turn them to blue and red as Top and Bottom?